# Django migrations - order of execution

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have two apps and

- Yesterday I decided to make a model (M) in app1. In app2, i decided to create a data migration and create an instance of that model through migrations. I `mademigrations` and committed.
- Today, I changed my mind and decided to remove model M completely.

Diagram to illustrate my migrations.

```
        myproject/
        ├── app1/
        │   ├── migrations/
        │   │   └── app1_0001.py ──> Create model M.
        │   │   └── app1_0002.py ──> Drop model M.
        ├── app2/
        │   ├── migrations/
        │   │   └── app2_0001.py ──> Data migration for Model M.
```

However, when trying to `python manage.py test -v 2`, I get the following error when migration `app2_0001.py` is being applied.

```
Applying app1.app1_0001... OK
Applying app1.app1_0002... OK
Applying app2.app2_0001... ERROR

LookupError: "App 'app1' doesn't have a 'M' model."
```

Why is `app2.app2_0001` executing after `app1.app1_0002` and not before it?
Here is the `app2.app2_0001.py` file:

```py
# Generated by Django 3.2.7 on 2023-06-09 13:38

from django.db import migrations


def code(apps, schema_editor):
    M = apps.get_model('app1', 'M') # this is the line that errors....
    M.objects.create()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('app1', 'app1.app1_0001'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(code),
    ]
```

Comment: Dependencies means that these are guaranteed to have run, that does not mean that they stopped at that dependency, otherwise one would easily get into a deadlock. We know thus that `app1.app1_0001` has run, but it is possible other dependencies hav erun before.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is `app2.app2_0001` executing after `app1.app1_0002` and not before it?

Because nothing says that it should be done otherwise. Usually it runs one app at a time.

Dependencies means that these are guaranteed to have run, that does not mean that they stopped at that dependency, otherwise one would easily get into a deadlock. We know thus that `app1.app1_0001` has run, but it is possible other dependencies have run before.

Django performs a [*topological sorting* algorithm <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to find a linearization that respects the dependencies, but there can be several ways to organize this.

You can however force Django to run `app2.app2_0001` before `app1.app1_0002`, simply by adding a dependency in `app1.app1_00002`:

```
# app1/migrations/0002.py

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('app1', 'app1.app1_0001'),
        ('app2', 'app2.app2_0001'),  # force that app2.app2_0001 runs first
    ]

    operations = [
        # …
    ]
```